# Android OpenGL ES Transparent Background

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, transparent

I'm building an Android app that takes advantage of OpenGL. As it stands, the background for the `GLSurfaceView` is dynamically generated by my code and loaded in as a texture and drawn with `glDrawTexfOES`. Which is "ok", but I can simply display the image much more smoothly to its own surface (without OpenGL). Is there any way that I can make the background of a `GLSurfaceView` transparent? I've heard some rumors that this can be done with `setEGLConfigChooser`, but I haven't found any confirmation. Ultimately, I'd like to take a surface which I'm drawing to and put the `GLSurfaceView` over it to achieve a layered effect.

I know this is a tricky and is quite possibly infeasible, but any input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about Open GL but if you take a look in the API examples there's a Class called TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity in package com.example.android.apis.graphics. 

Does that help?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just some simple changes that I did to get this to work.

On my `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
            GL10.GL_FASTEST);

     gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
     gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

On my `GLSurfaceView`:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: I have set the GLSurfaceView as you wrote, and put the upper code in my custom GL renderer, and I still get a black Background. Do you have any ideas on why that might be.

Comment: This WORKED for me. But, the contents of my view have gone blank as well. There's only a white canvas but nothing draws on it. Any help?

Comment: I just removed the given code from _onSurfaceCreated()_ method and it worked for me like I wanted. All I'm using now are the two lines of codes in my **GLSurfaceView**'s _init()_ method.

Answer (score 23):

Your `GLSurfaceView` also requires `setZOrderOnTop(true);`

Comment: and for this minimum sdk level 6 is needed.

Comment: This will solve the issue, But you won't be able to display any other view on top of GLSurfaceView if needed.

Comment: I spent all of yesterday working on a workaround for that. The solution is to implement Romain's answer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE and making sure you call setOpacity(false) in the constructor for the view as well as enabling alpha via other answers here (this solution does NOT require setZOrderOnTop())

Answer (score 10):

I use my own GLSurfaceView class to display charts (transparent background / overlay).
My extended GLSurfaceView is embed via XML into a popover window.

```
<com.dsignmatters.iq_fitfunlite.GLPieChartView          
    android:id="@+id/gameprogress_chart"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ...
```

As part of the activity I added this code:

```
mGamesuccessPieChart = (GLSurfaceView) gameprogressView.findViewById(R.id.gameprogress_chart);
mGamesuccessPieChart.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Last but not least my GLSurfaceView looks like this:

```
public class GLPieChartView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public GLPieChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initGL();
    }

    public GLPieChartView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initGL();
    }

    void initGL() {
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
        setRenderer(new GLPieChartRenderer());
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);     
    } 
}
```

My renderer class `GLPieChartRenderer` does not call `glClearColor` at all.

Comment: Please don't duplicate your answers across questions. If one of the questions is a duplicate of the other, then flag it for closure (or leave a comment indicating that it's a duplicate -- a higher rep user will then flag or vote to close it).  If the questions truly are different, then tailor your answer to each question posed.

Answer (score 5):

Code sample at the end is for enabling transparency with `GLSurfaceView`. But before using transparency with `GLSurfaceView`, consider the following negative points.

1. Enabling transparency requires that you use `setZOrderOnTop` on `GLSurfaceView`. That will prevent you from placing any other views ( e.g. `TextView` ) on top of your transparent `GLSurfaceView`. Even Navigation drawers cannot slide above the transparent `GLSurfaceView`( ignoring [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133690/gl-surface-and-visibility-gone/12133901#12133901) ). Transparent or not, `GLSurfaceView` can only exist above or  below other android views and not in between them.
2. Transparency requires that you use `setEGLConfigChooser` and `setFormat` as in below example. That means, you cannot get what would have been default format chosen by system which would have been the best for that particular device. More importantly, you will need to ensure that the device has the supported format and chose alternatives if expected format isn't present as in this gsoc [example](https://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java#90).

**Other options to transparency**.

3. Running `Tracer` for opengl in Android, will show that, background images for activities are drawn as opengl textures. So instead of making `GLSurfaceView` transparent, if possible, you can as well render your background as an opengl texture in GLSurfaceView.
4. Also, alpha channel or transparency on the surface is not pre requirement for alpha blending in opengl. Both are independent.
5. `TextureView` ([trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12061419/1180117)) is good alternative if your opengl component is to be embedded between other views. This [breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/) game is a very good example for `GLSurfaceView` 2d drawing in Android.

Below sample with layout xml and code for transparent `GLSurfaceView` with background.

1. Layout xml file with `green` color background

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:background="#00FFFF">

   <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
       android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. MainActivity.java file. Change `ALPHA` variable from 0.0 to 1.0 to see surface color `red` mixing with background activity color `green`

   ```
   package com.example.transparentsurfaceview;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
   import android.opengl.GLES20;
   import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
   import android.os.Bundle;

   import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
   import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       private GLSurfaceView mSurfaceView;
       private static float ALPHA = 0.5f;
       private static float RED   = 1.0f;
       private static float GREEN = 0.0f;
       private static float BLUE  = 0.0f;

       protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
           super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
           setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
           mSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById( R.id.mySurfaceView );

           mSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion( 2 );
           mSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop( true );
           mSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser( 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0 );
           mSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat( PixelFormat.RGBA_8888 );

           mSurfaceView.setRenderer( new GLSurfaceView.Renderer() {
               public void onSurfaceCreated( GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig ) {
                   GLES20.glClearColor( RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA );
               }

               public void onSurfaceChanged( GL10 gl10, int i, int i2 ) {}

               public void onDrawFrame( GL10 gl10 ) {
                   GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: `GLSurfaceView` **is** a subclass of `View`. See the inheritance hierarchy at the top of the documentation page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html.

Answer (score 1):

you should make sure the activity background is transparent!

If the activity's background is opaque, say white by default, then even when the content view (the glsurfaceview) is translucent, it will display the activity's white background as its background.

You can set the activity background transparency in the Android.manifest where it is declared, see the official API demo TranslucentGLSurfaceViewActivity for help