# Android, Transparent sub-GLSurfaceView in layout?

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, transparent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android OpenGL ES Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034822/android-opengl-es-transparent-background)

I'd like to display some 3d object on top of the normal 2d ui layout screen.

The 2d ui screen has background image, and GLSurfaceView is child of the content layout.

I tried the same technique of the Translucent GLSurfaceView in ApiDemos sample,

but GLSurfaceView clears all and shows black background.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:background="@drawable/my_background_image"
>

...

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glview"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:windowIsTranslucent="true" (i'm not sure this is right)
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
...
glview = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview);
glview.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
glview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
glview.setRenderer(this);
...
gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
...
```

---

Can I preserve the underlying background image in this situation?

Answer (score 25):

this solved it for me:

```
    glview = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glview); 

    glview.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);

    glview.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(this));
    glview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    // this made it work for me - works only from sdk level 6 on, though....
    glview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Comment: @P.Melch This make GlSurfaceView on top of all the views. Now I am unable to set another view over the GlSurfaceView. Is there any other way to make the GlSurfaceView transparent.

Comment: @P.Melch Same problem Zorder-top make other view go behind GLsurfaceview

Comment: AFAIK the only way with surfaceview is to chose front or back placement. if you want to have a more complex layout, i think TextureView is the one for you ( availble starting with API 14, though)