# VideoView not visible in FrameLayout when placed over a SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-framelayout, vitamio

My `VideoView` seems to only be visible when it is the only child of my `FrameLayout`. When there is a second child -- a `SurfaceView` (even when the `VideoView` is created afterwards, giving it a higher z-index) -- then the `VideoView` is no longer visible.

I have an extension of Vitamio's `VideoView`:

```
public class AnimationCanvas extends VideoView{
public static AnimationCanvas animationCanvas;
public AnimationCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    animationCanvas = this;
    setVideoURI(Uri.parse(MainActivity.toRightPath));
    requestFocus();
    start();
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    setVideoURI(Uri.parse(MainActivity.animationFilePath));
                    requestFocus();
                    start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    System.out.println("Down");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

And here's the main.xml file:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.temporary.alexcameronelijahapp.gui.MainCanvas
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.temporary.alexcameronelijahapp.gui.AnimationCanvas
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The `AnimationCanvas` works fine when I delete or comment out the `MainCanvas` view of the main.xml file (these lines):

```
<com.temporary.gui.MainCanvas
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I was under the impression that, in a `FrameLayout`, the Z-indices are assigned in the order in which they were added to the layout (the last one added has the highest z-index). However, the `AnimationCanvas` is not visible so long as the `MainCanvas` is there as well...

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** It would be good to know that I am, in fact, drawing many Bitmaps on my instance of `MainCanvas`.

Secondly, if I set `android:background="#000000"` in the xml code of my `AnimationCanvas`, it becomes visible over the `MainCanvas`, but the Video itself still won't show (as if the black background is somehow covering up the video?)

**EDIT #2:** I believe I have found the issue, but still no solution. When I comment out my paint method within my `MainCanvas` class, meaning that no Bitmaps are painted to the canvas, then the `AnimationCanvas` is visible. It's almost as if, even though the `AnimationCanvas` is on top of the `MainCanvas`, the `MainCanvas's` locked canvas is somehow on top of the `AnimationCanvas's` VideoView canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SurfaceView` behaves differently from other widgets, when it comes to things like visibility and z-order. For details, see [GL Surface and Visibility: Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133690/gl-surface-and-visibility-gone/12133901#12133901). Most importantly, they just ignore visibility.
Also note that `VideoView` is just another example of SurfaceView.

Try one of the suggestions in the post above. In your case, you might also try using the same `SurfaceView` as the destination for both your drawing and your video.

Comment: Removing the view from the hierarchy altogether worked perfectly for me. Thank you.