# Transparent background for AR application (Android glasses)

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I use augmented reality see-through glasses running android 4.2.

I would like to add objects in the user's view.

I have successfully implemented the objects with OpenGL, but the background is not transparent, which is kind of annoying with see-through glasses.

I tried descriptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034822/android-opengl-es-transparent-background) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249362/any-way-to-make-an-entire-android-opengl-es-scene-transparent), none of them really worked.

I have not very much experience with OpenGL, so I would appreciate some hints how to achieve this.

Comment: You might be saying Cardboard right?

Comment: No, it's for Epson Moverio or ODG glasses.