# ANR TextureView on Galaxy S2 (GPU driver issue?)

Tags: android, opengl-es, galaxy, glsurfaceview, android-anr-dialog

I have multiple TextureView inside a ListView that plays an opengl video stream. The code works fine on Nexus 4 (4.2), Galaxy S3 (4.1), and HTC One (4.0.3). However, ANR happens when I try to scroll the listview on S2 (SPH-D710VMUB, Virgin Mobile, 4.0.4) when opengl threads are running (deadlock). The ANR trace is provided below (isHardwareAccelerated() = true on listview).

Also note that if GLSurfaceView is used to handle the same openGL code, it works fine, but the Z-order messes up with multiple SurfaceViews in the same window for ICS devices. The GLTextureView is converted via instructions [Converting from GLSurfaceView to TextureView (via GLTextureView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061419/converting-from-glsurfaceview-to-textureview-via-gltextureview)

EDIT 1: Tried another implementation of GLTextureView, was able to locate the exact line.
"eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay display, EGLSurface surface);" will block on S2 for some reason.

Someone noticed: http://vec.io/posts/a-workaround-to-fix-opengl-eglswapbuffers-freezing 
glFinish(); is needed. Any idea?

EDIT 2: Adding glFinish() or eglWaitGL() does not help. :( Suspect that they return immediately regardless....

EDIT 3: To reproduce it using https://github.com/eaglesakura/gltextureview: 
See https://github.com/eaglesakura/gltextureview/issues/1

EDIT 4: In case anyone is wondering, this is my implementation of the GLTextureView (https://github.com/edisonw/jjmpeg/tree/jjmpeg-1.0-dev/jjmpeg-android/src/com/edisonwang/android/player) It also includes FFMpeg playback stuff.

EDIT 5: It turns out to be a possible Qualcomm Adreno 200 series bug: https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/mobile-gaming-graphics-optimization-adreno/11525

```
        DALVIK THREADS:
        (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
        "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
          | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c30460 self=0x129c0
          | sysTid=21854 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074746664
          | schedstat=( 434522015 268952863 603 ) utm=34 stm=9 core=0
          at android.view.GLES20Canvas.nUpdateTextureLayer(Native Method)
          at android.view.GLES20TextureLayer.update(GLES20TextureLayer.java:77)
          at android.view.TextureView.applyUpdate(TextureView.java:388)
          at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:276)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10586)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10549)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10549)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850)
          at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3225)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
          at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2271)
          at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3220)
          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11150)
          at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3728)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10586)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10549)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10549)
          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
          at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10549)
          at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:842)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1735)
          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2547)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


    "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=19 WAIT
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415cdf00 self=0x3aa178
      | sysTid=8059 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=4722816
      | schedstat=( 369083 125724959 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      - waiting on <0x415ce020> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=19 (AsyncTask #2)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)


    "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415ca7d8 self=0x30c370
      | sysTid=8050 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3105360
      | schedstat=( 448085 5989790 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      - waiting on <0x415ca970> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AsyncTask #1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

    "GLThread 320" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41535368 self=0x2f7308
      | sysTid=8049 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2690528
      | schedstat=( 1744387397 1741438396 2048 ) utm=169 stm=5 core=1
      at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglSwapBuffers(Native Method)
ndroid.player.GLTextureView$GLThread.run(GLTextureView.java:1261)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4150bfd8 self=0x217e08
  | sysTid=8038 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2155984
  | schedstat=( 1496167 16950375 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414fb130 self=0x1bd740
  | sysTid=8037 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1595520
  | schedstat=( 2633041 25123960 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f7490 self=0x182a50
  | sysTid=8036 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1433120
  | schedstat=( 288708 6619500 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f7338 self=0x105230
  | sysTid=8035 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1662112
  | schedstat=( 3763081 5489124 25 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40c265d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f71d0 self=0xfa1f0
  | sysTid=8034 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1662016
  | schedstat=( 1831625 1206249 33 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40c264f8> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f70e0 self=0x1b8688
  | sysTid=8033 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=747976
  | schedstat=( 182108462 246633083 1197 ) utm=11 stm=7 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f6ff8 self=0x206680
  | sysTid=8032 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1450968
  | schedstat=( 1964583 1505832 16 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f6f00 self=0x1b7dd8
  | sysTid=8031 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1660128
  | schedstat=( 4634792 2711334 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414f6e20 self=0x20adb8
  | sysTid=8028 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1365944
  | schedstat=( 132084797 114875290 96 ) utm=10 stm=2 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any ideas for how to debug this or why it happens?

Comment: I do think, without code, we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I have added the code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an official response from Google that this is indeed a driver bug from Samsung (supposedly fixed) for this very specific device.