# OpenGL API glClearColor alpha channel does nothing

Tags: opengl, kivy

I use kivy in my application and try to create a transparent background window. I do this with:

```
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,0)
Window.clear()
```

That produces a white window - opaque.
Kivy directly calls `glClearColor` from the OpenGL 4 API (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/).
The [docs](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glClear.xhtml) say, that the last parameter is the alpha channel so I expect my window to be transparent.

Do I have a mistake in my thinking or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you check the GL pipeline state? Is `BLENDING` actually enabled by the framework you're using? There is no question about what `glClearColor` but as pleluron mentioned, this will have no effect without blending enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Default pixel formats are often RGB, so the alpha value is only used for blending operations. You need the correct pixel format to make your surfaces transparent, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2196281/5778900).

Comment: mh ok - i have to adapt my question since iam on desktop and not on android... ty anyway

Comment: I made the assumption kivy was build on top of OpenGL ES - but there is no cross-platform solution for this. Kivy should implement this themselves, but to answer your question, `glClearColor()` works as intended.

Comment: Kivy uses the open gl version in the system when available. In my case that's opengl 4. Thx for your clarification!