# OpenGL scene with transparent background + native widgets below and above

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, transparency, glsurfaceview, textureview

I'm trying to achieve the following view:

[image]

If the views were layered (bottom to top):

- layer 1: basic XML layout (image, buttons etc)
- layer 2: OpenGL scene with transparent background such that we can see through
- layer 3: some widgets over the OpenGL scene (ie `TextView`)

I've used `GLSurfaceView` and `TextureView` along those [lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034822/android-opengl-es-transparent-background), without success. I can set opacity to the surface, but the whole view becomes semi-transparent, and `setZOrderOnTop` has to be set to `true`, so no widget can live atop.  I've also tried [rajawali3d](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali), same result

Can this be achieve at all? Using stock views? Or a library?

update: also tried [JPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/), same results.

update 2: is seems there was way to have a floating OpenGL view with `UnityPlayer` when it was using a `SurfaceView`, but it's no longer the case in the newer SDK.

Comment: do buttons need to be in the layer below??

Comment: No, that was just as example.

Comment: @Paulo there's a 24h grace period. thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @etrusks: there's no solution for opengl+native widgets. If you want transparency on the opengl view, it has to be at the top, and nothing can be drawn over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thats what I figured - started to implement those top views inside openGL view.